# np.linspace() returns imprecise values

Tags: python, numpy

This drives me nuts:

```
In[1]:  list(np.linspace(.05,.5,10,endpoint=True))
Out[1]: [0.05,
         0.1,
         0.15000000000000002,
         0.2,
         0.25,
         0.3,
         0.35000000000000003,
         0.4,
         0.45,
         0.5]
```

Why is it so hard to get uniformly distributed values in a closed interval?

Comment: because some float values cannot be saved precisely in binary. for example, `0.15=0.125+0.015625+...=2^-3 + 2^-6 + ....`. they just cannot be displayed as finite float, just like `1/3=3*10^-1 + 3*10^-2 + ...` in base 10.

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions.

[...]

Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Because floating point numbers are a PITA but there is no need to get angry.
You can just use

```
list(np.round(np.linspace(.05,.5,10,endpoint=True), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Python [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> The problem is easier to understand at first in base 10. Consider the fraction 1/3. You can approximate that as a base 10 fraction:
>
> ```
> 0.3
> ```
>
> or, better,
>
> ```
> 0.33
> ```
>
> or, better,
>
> ```
> 0.333
> ```
>
> and so on. No matter how many digits you’re willing to write down, the result will never be exactly 1/3, but will be an increasingly better approximation of 1/3.
>
> In the same way, no matter how many base 2 digits you’re willing to use, the decimal value 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a base 2 fraction. In base 2, 1/10 is the infinitely repeating fraction
>
> ```
> 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...
> ```

Your best bet is to keep the floats in the numpy array until you really need to convert it into a list, for whatever reason. When you do so, as you probably know, you can use the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function to round each float to the nearest, say sixteenth:

```
[round(i, 16) for i in np.linspace(.05, .5, 10)]
```

Output:

```
[0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5]
```

Of course, you'll might to use a number smaller than `16` in other cases.